# Tomcat 9 deploy into ROOT

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, развертывание, war

Есть `*.war` файл. Если его положить в папку `webapps`, то он автоматически деплоится в подпапку с именем таким же как у файла. Нужно его задеплоить в корень.

Сервер на `Ubuntu`, графического интерфейса нет, через браузер это сделать нельзя, давать доступ к папке `manager` с других хостов тоже нельзя.

Хотелось бы как-то автоматизировать этот процесс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что нужно сделать:

0. Сервер установлен в папку `/opt/tomcat/`
1. Останавливаем сервер `$sudo service tomcat stop`
2. Удаляем папку `/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT`
3. Создаем папку `/opt/tomcat/myapps`
4. Создаем файл `/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml`
5. В файле пишем:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Context path="" docBase="/opt/tomcat/myapps/{name-of-the-app}.war" />
   ```
6. Кладем нужный нам файл `{name-of-the-app}.war` в папку `/opt/tomcat/myapps`
7. Запускаем сервер `$sudo service tomcat start`

При передеплое достаточно заменить этот файл на новый - остальное tomcat сделает сам.