# После перезагрузки сервера Tomcat приложения не запускаются до передеплоя

Tags: tomcat, centos, развертывание

На севере `CentOS` установлен сервер приложений `Tomcat`. В нем развернут проект в корневой папке `webapps/ROOT` как описано здесь: [Tomcat 9 deploy into ROOT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/713579/236980)

После физической перезагрузки сервера поднимается служба `Tomcat`, но приложение в корневой папке `webapps/ROOT` остается недоступно.

Если заново скопировать `{name-of-the-app}.war` в папку `myapps`, то `Tomcat` заново разворачивает архив, и приложение становится доступно.

---

На сколько я понимаю, приложения должны подниматься вместе с `Tomcat`-ом, но почему-то этого не происходит.

**Что я делаю не так?**

---

**UPD:** - Логи сервера приложений

**catalina.out** - после перезапуска сервера

```
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.152 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.155 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 4 2018 22:13:41 UTC
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.155 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.12.0
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.156 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.156 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.156 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.156 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181-amd64/jre
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.156 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-b13
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.156 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.156 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.12
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.156 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.12
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.157 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/apr/lib
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.17] using APR version [1.4.8].
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.166 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017]
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.338 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.355 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.367 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.configureUpgradeProtocol The ["https-openssl-apr-8443"] connector has been configured to support negotiation to [h2] via ALPN
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.367 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-apr-8443"]
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.428 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.429 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.430 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 902 ms
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.476 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.477 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.489 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.12/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml]
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.517 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [] in deployment descriptor [/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.12/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml] has been ignored
13-Sep-2018 22:09:11.527 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.12/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml] with an external docBase means the directory [/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.12/webapps/ROOT] in the appBase will be ignored
13-Sep-2018 22:09:12.431 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

**catalina.out** - после передеплоя

```
13-Sep-2018 22:12:42.714 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [210,235] milliseconds.
13-Sep-2018 22:12:42.786 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.12/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml] has finished in [211,297] ms
13-Sep-2018 22:12:42.792 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
13-Sep-2018 22:12:42.804 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-apr-8443"]
13-Sep-2018 22:12:42.815 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
13-Sep-2018 22:12:42.825 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 211395 ms
13-Sep-2018 22:12:52.791 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload Reloading context []
13-Sep-2018 22:12:52.794 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [] has started
13-Sep-2018 22:12:53.966 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
13-Sep-2018 22:12:53.994 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [] is completed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как выяснилось, `Tomcat` на самом деле запускался и поднимал приложение, но делал это очень медленно, а передеплой просто ускорял этот процесс. В некоторых случаях загрузка `Tomcat` вместе со всеми приложениями может длиться **~17 МИНУТ**.

Проблема связана с ошибкой [**JDK-4705093**](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4705093) при генерации `SecureRandom` для `SHA1PRNG`.

```
# Неочевидно, правда.. !! Но такое тоже бывает..
```

---

#### Решение:

1. Открываем файл

   ```
   $JAVA_PATH/jre/lib/security/java.security
   ```
2. Находим строку

   ```
   securerandom.source=file:/dev/random
   ```
3. Заменяем ее на строку

   ```
   securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom
   ```

---

<sup>Более подробное описание ошибки: [«Tomcat7 starts too late on Ubuntu 14.04 x64»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26432537/8280225).</sup>